# Can I use syntax/grammar in angular2 on angular1 ? What is the difference between angular2 and 1?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I started learning Angular and I'm getting used to Angular structure and grammar. However, my workplace required me to use AngularJS to keep consistency and less import. Does AngularJS support Angular syntax (components etc)?

Comment: The reason angular2 came in place was to have structured programming. Although you may understnad Angular 1 as their concpet is still the same.

Comment: I heard that for angular1 later release, it also support Angular2 's new concepts like component?

Comment: It's grammar, with an "a".

Comment: AngularJS is a different framework. You need to learn it (like basically everything else). It shares some concepts with Angular, but that's about it. Read the documentation.